# How to polygon a file with tif extension as desired?

Tags: python, polygon, tiff, gdal, qgis

[image]

This is an image of agricultural land in which I did the clustering operation, now I want to consider each rectangle as a polygon regardless of the value of each pixel, what should I do?

I wrote python code for this and used the qgis program, but it didn't do what I wanted

This is the code that I use for polygonizing.

```
input_path = "/home/saeed/Desktop/SatPlat_Goats/39SUR/mask/mask.tif"
poliginize_shape_path = "Polgonize"
polygonize_cmd = f"gdal_polygonize.py -8 {input_path} -b 1 {poliginize_shape_path}"
os.system(polygonize_cmd)

# Open the input shapefile
in_ds = ogr.Open('/home/saeed/Desktop/SatPlat_Goats/39SUR/polygon/out.shp')
print(in_ds)
# Get the input layer
in_layer = in_ds.GetLayer()

# Create a new shapefile to hold the filtered polygons
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
out_ds = driver.CreateDataSource("39SUR/polygon/poly100000")
out_layer = out_ds.CreateLayer('polygons', geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
# Copy the input layer's fields to the output layer
in_layer_defn = in_layer.GetLayerDefn()
for i in range(in_layer_defn.GetFieldCount()):
    field_defn = in_layer_defn.GetFieldDefn(i)
    out_layer.CreateField(field_defn)
# Loop through the input layer's features
for in_feat in in_layer:
    # Get the feature's geometry and calculate its area
    geom = in_feat.GetGeometryRef()
    area = geom.GetArea()
    area = area * 10000000000
# print(area)

    # Check if the feature's area is greater than or equal to 10 square meters
    if area >= 100000:

        # Create a new feature in the output layer and set its geometry and attributes
        out_feat = ogr.Feature(out_layer.GetLayerDefn())
        out_feat.SetGeometry(geom.Clone())
        for i in range(out_feat.GetFieldCount()):
            out_feat.SetField(out_layer.GetLayerDefn().GetFieldDefn(i).GetNameRef(), in_feat.GetField(i))

        # Add the feature to the output layer
        out_layer.CreateFeature(out_feat)
print("3333333333333333333333")
# Close the shapefiles
in_ds = None
out_ds = None
```

This code polygonizes the image, but it has problems. For example, a part of agricultural land whose NDVI is low due to some problems is considered separate from agricultural land.

Comment: Please click [edit] and show your code and explain what happened exactly rather than just saying *"it didn't do what you wanted"*.

Comment: OK, I will edit it now

Comment: An alternative that's quite far from your current approach, but I developed a procedure and tools in python to support doing custom segmentations on orthophotos. I happen to be working on field boundary delineation as we speak based on this procedure. It is work in progress and not ready at all, but I just added a rough sample project of a field delineation... if your current approach doesn't work out you could have a look: [orthoseg](https://github.com/orthoseg/orthoseg)

Comment: @Pieter Can you explain a little about it, what it does and what direction it goes?

Comment: @Milad_py99 orthoseg uses machine learning (deep neural networks) for the segmentation. So in most cases creating a train dataset is the main thing to be done. Because I wrote orthoseg with aerial images in mind, it only supports 3 bands at the moment, so in this case I've also experimented a bit with finding the 3 most interesting bands to include to segment on.

Comment: I've been busy with other things the past time, so I didn't get to it to put more time into it, but this is a [screenshot](https://github.com/orthoseg/orthoseg/blob/master/sample_projects/fields/img/Impression_minimal_training_dataset.jpg) of the current result based on +- two hours of digitizing training samples. If you would spend some extra hours of adding samples the result will quickly become significantly better.